# Weird behaviour using MaterialComponents and BottomNavigationView. Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationView from material design library and everything seems to be ok.

[image]

I need to use new [badges](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigationView.md#badges) so I have upgrade it to version 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

But I don't know why changing the version draws like an inverse triangle inside my bottomNavigationView. Its bit difficult to see in black background. But it is there and I have no idea why but it happens in all my devices after upgrading.

This is my BottomNavView xml

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        style="@style/MainBottomMenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/bottom_nav_icon_size"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


 <style name="MainBottomMenu">
        <item name="android:background">@color/gray_25t</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@drawable/nav_item_color_state_light</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@drawable/nav_item_color_state_light</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/padding_nano</item>
    </style>
```

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: First step try to use the stable release 1.1.0 instead of 1.1.0-alpha09.

Comment: It happens the same in 1.1.0 version.

Comment: Can you please share what you have written in <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView/> or else please try adding app:itemBackground="@drawable/with_custom_selector"

Comment: I have updated the question. I have added also itemBackground but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved setting elevation to 0 dp

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1077